# Codeigniter Error Input data

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I try to insert data using `codeigniter`. But when my data have a question symbol, I get some error. I try direct into database its work properly but when I try run in `codeigniter` it's not working.

Can anyone help me, or any idea for solve this problem.

My query:

```
INSERT INTO WIK_POLICY (PRODUCT,ADV) VALUES ('CUP' ,'are you familiar with cup?')
```

Comment: INSERT INTO WIK_POLICY (PRODUCT,ADV) VALUES ('CUP' ,'are you familiar with cup?')
that's is My query.

Comment: What error did `codeigniter` throw?

Comment: show your code ??????

Comment: Need to know the Codeigniter script that produces the error

Comment: show your db insertion code and error you encountered..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have many ways to insert data in your database.
Ill show the bests ways to do it.

Using set and insert function:

```
$this->db->set('name', $name);
$this->db->insert('mytable');
```

//RESULT : Produces: INSERT INTO mytable (name) VALUES ('{$name}');

Using $this->db->insert():

```
$data = array(
   'title' => 'My title' ,
   'name' => 'My Name' ,
   'date' => 'My date'
);

$this->db->insert('mytable', $data);
```

// Produces: INSERT INTO mytable (title, name, date) VALUES ('My title', 'My name', 'My date')

Try check if the structure of ADV field in mysql, check if is varchar or text and your limit of Characters.

I recommend you to use this function:
$this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);

The Profiler Class will display benchmark results, queries you have run, and $_POST data at the bottom of your pages. This information can be useful during development in order to help with debugging and optimization.

Answer (score 1):

Use Codeigniter Standard instead of simple query,

```
$data = array(
       'title' => 'My title' ,
       'name' => 'My Name' ,
       'date' => 'My date'
    );

    $this->db->insert('mytable', $data); 

    // Produces: INSERT INTO mytable (title, name, date) VALUES ('My title', 'My name', 'My date')
```

Reference :

[CodeIgniter Insert Query](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#insert)

If you want to use simple method then,

```
$query = $this->db->query("YOUR QUERY");
```